# How far back does a prometheus query fetch data

Tags: prometheus

When querying prometheus without any functions, is the result returned just from the last scrape, or is it from the last minute, etc?

```
my_metric{label1=myval}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's roughly from the last scrape, https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness has more detail.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, I think what was confusing was the wording 'no value is returned for that time series'. In my case, a value is being returned, but that value is not being incremented in the previous 5 minutes. I assume this would be the same situation.